# Can we install and send updates for winjs metro apps using the Squirrel.Windows

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows, squirrel.windows

I have developer WinJs metro app for windows 8 and 10. To send the updates we found this https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows (An installation and update framework for Windows desktop apps)
Can we use this for windows applications developed in WinJs?

Comment: Unlikely, WinJS Metro apps are handled by the windows store which provides its own updates

Comment: Agree. I am looking for other options too.

Comment: Why not use the windows store itself? Did you know you can have private apps in the windows store, that aren't available for general consumption but only to selected organizations? It's actually reasonably easy to set up, and afaik free.

Comment: Its not free. There are charges at the time of registration. Also not supporting trial/demo account to setup. So that once we confidant/confirm then we will paid the amount and continue. We have to paid at the time to account opening. I will look for that option also but before that want to try for other available options.

Comment: @TKoL can you please share the link of windows store code push which is free.

Comment: As @TKoL said WinJS Metro apps are handled by the windows store. you could not hot patching your app without windows store.

Currently we have not provided trial account to publishing app for free. However, if your are `Student Account`, you could publish your application for free. Please note it has a rigorous certification process. For more you could refer to [**Student Account**](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thank you. I will check.